# How to set beforeShowDay for long back dates in bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

hi I'm trying to use a datepicker bootstrap with a long date backwards selection. now I can only get 45 days back.

```
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var tgl = ['15/08/2018', '16/08/2018', '17/08/2018']; 
        var dt_ddmmyyyy = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();              
        if (tgl.indexOf(dt_ddmmyyyy) != -1) {               
            return true;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
    }   
});
```

the code will disable all dates except the date specified in the array, but only a maximum of 45 days back. so the date of the array is not included.
any suggestions for this problem?
Thank you for your help

Comment: try with my answer

Answer (score 1):

TRy this... Use `'15/08/2018'` to `'15/8/2018'`

```js
$( "#js-date" ).datepicker({
    multidate: true,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var tgl = ['15/8/2018', '16/8/2018', '17/8/2018']; 
        var dt_ddmmyyyy = date.getDate() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getFullYear();              
        if (tgl.indexOf(dt_ddmmyyyy) != -1) {               
            return true;
        } else {
                return false;
        }
    }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="js-date">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another example, `("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)` will get month in 2 digit format.

```js
$('#datepicker').val("08-15-2018");/* for demo purpose */

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  multidate: true,
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var tgl = ['15/08/2018', '16/08/2018', '17/08/2018'];
    var dt_ddmmyyyy = date.getDate() + '/' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
    if (tgl.indexOf(dt_ddmmyyyy) != -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
td.day.disabled {
  opacity: 0.2;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<input id="datepicker">
```